# Add xsl:param only on first iteration of the xsl:for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

Can I add `xls:param` only on first iteration of the loop. **I'm using xsl version 1.0**. If we have:

```
  <TestObject>
    <xsl:for-each select="TestObject">
      <item>
        <ParamValue>
          <xsl:value-of select='$Test'/>
        </ParamValue>            
        <TEXT>
          <xsl:value-of select="Text" />
        </TEXT>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </TestObject>
```

If we have 3 `Text` in `TestObject`. This is the wanted result:

```
  <TestObject>       
      <item>
        <ParamValue>
          Value of the parameter
        </ParamValue>            
        <TEXT>
          Text1
        </TEXT>
      </item>
      <item>
        <ParamValue></ParamValue>            
        <TEXT>
          Text2
        </TEXT>
      </item>
      <item>
        <ParamValue></ParamValue>            
        <TEXT>
          Text3
        </TEXT>
      </item>
  </TestObject>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position) function effectively gives you the iteration number:

```
  <TestObject>
    <xsl:for-each select="TestObject">
      <item>
        <ParamValue>
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1"><xsl:value-of select='$Test'/></xsl:if>
        </ParamValue>            
        <TEXT>
          <xsl:value-of select="Text" />
        </TEXT>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </TestObject>
```

(I say "effectively" because an XSLT processor doesn't *have* to implement `for-each` using a sequential loop.  XSLT is a functional language without side effects so the processor is free to process the nodes in any order or even in parallel, as long as it assembles the final output in the correct way.  The position() function returns the position of the node currently being processed, within the list of nodes that the for-each `select`-ed).

Comment: Thanks man, I used this in the past but I totally forgot it !